# Fundamental Difference Between Variable Definition and Function Definition

Tags: racket

I am learning Racket via the book `Realm of Racket`. I noticed that defining a variable and defining a function is done via the same keyword - `define`. This got me thinking about what the fundamental difference is between a function that takes no arguments and simply returns the value `5`, and a variable that returns the value `5`. i.e.:

```
(define fiveVar 5)

(define (fiveFun)
  5)
```

(Apologies if camel-case is not the right naming convention - just picked up the book and don't know any Lisp).

At first glance, it seems to me that I am simply giving a name to the value `5` in both cases. In fact, I can even re-attach the name `fiveFun`: `(set fiveFun 6)`, just as I can with a variable.

So again, it seems to me that there is no difference between defining a variable and defining a function. In both cases, I am giving a name to a data type. In the case of the function data type, it can be applied, whereas a number cannot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much, yeah. In fact, the `(define (f x ...) ...)` notation is just a convenient abbreviation in Scheme and other Lisp-1s, which is in contrast to Common Lisp and other Lisp-2s which separate functions and values into separate namespaces.

In Racket and Scheme, when you write this:

```
(define (f x) (+ x 1))
```

It’s actually just a shorthand notation for writing this:

```
(define f (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))
```

The `lambda` form is a special form that produces a *procedure value*, but the binding that is created, in this case `f`, is no different from the binding for an ordinary value. Since procedures are just values like any other, this makes using so-called “higher-order” functions—functions that accept functions as arguments—easy to write and use. For example, `filter` takes a function as its first argument:

```
> (filter even? '(1 2 3 4))
'(2 4)
```

Now, with that in mind, the function definition you wrote in your question is actually this, without the shorthand:

```
(define fiveFun (lambda () 5))
```

So then, consider the difference between these two things:

```
(define fiveVar 5)
(define fiveFun (lambda () 5))
```

Well, one of them is a number, `5`, and the other is a function with no arguments which, when applied, *produces* 5. Some languages, mostly purely functional ones, do not even have a *concept* of a function that takes no arguments, so there is no meaningful way to express `fiveFun` in those languages. In Racket, however, there are a couple reasons you might want such a function:

1. You can use a no-argument function to “delay” evaluation until another time, or even run it multiple times, which is useful if running the function has side effects. For example:

   ```
   > (define x (begin (displayln "Hello!") 5))
   Hello!
   > x
   5
   > x
   5

   > (define f (lambda () (displayln "Hello!") 5))
   > f
   #<procedure:f>
   > (f)
   Hello!
   5
   > (f)
   Hello!
   5
   ```
2. Also, a value might take a long *time* to produce, and you might want to defer its evaluation until it’s actually needed. You could use a zero-argument function to run the computation “lazily”, when the function is actually used.

As a small piece of terminology, a zero-argument function is often called a “thunk”, which you might see in some places in the Racket documentation. There’s even a form called `thunk` from `racket/function` which is a small shorthand for a zero-argument lambda.

Comment: Alexis, thank you for a great explanation. The long-hand form makes explicit exactly what I was thinking. Very similar to Haskell in this sense.

Comment: @StevenL. Yes, quite similar! The difference, of course, is that Haskell has no concept of no-argument functions, since Haskell is both lazy and pure, so they wouldn’t be useful.